# Error "No module named autopygui" after opening the compiled exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe, nuitka

I wrote the code using the pyautogui library. I tried to compile the file using modules such as pyinstaller, nuitka, auto-py-to-exe, but when opening the resulting file it gives the error "No module named pyautogui". How can I import this library into an exe file so that everything works and there are no errors?

I want to get an exe file that won't cause an error when opened. How can I do that?